# Tomcat Catalina Error logs not showing up on console

Tags: tomcat, logging

When I deploy my war file in tomcat, the SEVERE errors thrown by Catalina do not show up on console. For example NullPointerExceptions are not shown in the console making life hard sometimes. Instead they are shown in  $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/localhost*.log files.
What should I do to make these catalina logging information to show on the console.

Additional details:
I have log4j enabled in my application itself and logs related to that show up on the console without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html, it would seem that you can manipulate the file $CATALINA.BASE/conf/logging.properties to insure that the handlers push to where you want them to go.

Comment: needs the actual code to do this, and should not be a link